# Is there a Firefox addon that would change the "find on page" bar to be Chrome-like?

Tags: firefox, user-interface

I think that Chrome's UI design of Ctrl+F bar is better than Firefox's so I was trying to find an addon that would amend the look / position of the bar but no luck. Is there an addon like that or any other tips to make the "find on page" experience better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find Bar - like Google Chrome II
Puts the find bar to the top right similar to Google Chrome.

http://userstyles.org/styles/45007/find-bar-like-google-chrome-ii